# Understanding Haskells type signatures (e.g zipWith with (+))

Tags: haskell, signature, type-signature

I have a question regarding the type signatures in Haskell, which I find sometimes a bit difficult to unterstand. For example the type signature of `zipWith` is:

```
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

What I see here is that `zipWith` expects a function (with parameters of type `a` and `b`), a list with `a`s, a list with `b`s and it gives us a list of `c`s. But I do not unterstand why I can use `zipWith` with `(+)` for example, which has the signature:

```
(+) :: a -> a -> a
```

From my point of view the signature of `(+)` doesn't match with the signature of `(a -> b -> c)`. `(+)` only expects parameters of type `a`, while `(a -> b -> c)` expects parameters of different types: `a` and `b`. Can anyone give me a hint what is my fault?

Comment: Another way to look at the `zipWith` function is that it "lifts" a function of two arguments to the list monad since the signature could be written as `zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> ([a] -> [b] -> [c])`.  In the case of `(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int`, `a ~ Int`, `b ~ Int`, and `c ~ Int`, so `zipWith (+) :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(a -> b -> c)` means any function that takes a type `a` and a type `b` and returns a type `c`.
There is nothing to stop you from using a function that has the signature `(a -> a -> a)`, it just happens that in this case the types are all the same.

Assume you had a method with this signature:

```
zipWith' :: (a -> a -> a) -> [a] -> [a] -> [a]
```

you couldn't use a method with a signature of `(a -> b -> c)` in this case as the expected method signature is more restrictive.

Comment: Ah I see. So when I use different type parameters in the function signatures all the types can be the same. But in a type signature like (a -> a -> a) the 1. parameter has to have the same type as the 2. parameter, right?

Comment: Your first sentence is slightly misleading; it would be true for `(forall a b c. (a -> b -> c))`, but that type does not appear in `zipWith`’s signature.

Comment: @Meiner - Correct. In other words, `a -> a -> a` is a **particular instance** of `a -> b -> c`, where `b` happens to be the same as `a`, as does `c`.

Comment: The term for this process is **unification**.  The term is actually more general; in the context of type inference, it's why `a` can match `Int`, or why `[a] -> b` can match `[Bool] -> [Char] -> [Int -> Int]`.